# IllegalStateException when calling AudioRecord.start()

Tags: android, audio, capture, mediarecorder

I'm using AudioRecorder to record short audio clips but I'm getting IllegalStateException when calling AudioRecord.start() I've been looking for hours but can't find the cause of this...

I've set Audio Rec + Write External Storage permissions.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
// main activity...

// Audio inits
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(getTempPath());
```

...

```
// called the sound rec async

new SoundComponent(tvmic, pb, tb).execute(recorder);

// SoundComponent.java
// Getting IllegalStateException when calling recorder[0].start();

[..]
protected Long doInBackground(MediaRecorder... recorder) {


     try {
         recorder[0].prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("100", "prepare() failed");
        }




    while (tb.isChecked())
    {
        //publishProgress();
        //recorder[0].prepare();

         recorder[0].start(); // here it were it throws
         try {
             Thread.sleep(250);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        // int amplitude = recorder[0].getMaxAmplitude();

         recorder[0].stop();

    }


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

[..]

```
public String getTempPath() // audio temp path
{
    String path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    path+="/temp/audiorectemp.3gp";
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `AsyncTask` to do this?

Comment: It's a part of a more complex application. I've done video capture and sensor handling using asyncs without a problem.

Comment: You're starting your recorder object regardless of whether it prepares successfully or not. You should handle it different if it should enter that `IOException` catch block (i.e. "prepare() failed")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting and stopping the `MediaRecorder` multiple times in a loop probably isn't a good idea. Look closely at what you're doing, I've trimmed your code to make it easier to see...

```
while (tb.isChecked())
{
     recorder[0].start(); // here it were it throws
     // Sleep here
     recorder[0].stop();
}
```

It probably isn't throwing an exception the first time you call `start()` but it will on the second loop. See the state machine diagram...[MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

Also, to detect when the `doInBackground(...)` thread should be exited, ther is a method on `AsyncTask` which can be called from the UI thread to cancel it.

The loop should ideally be `while (!isCancelled())` and you should call the `AsyncTask.cancel(...)` method from the `onCheckedChanged` listener of `tb` in the main `Activity` code (assuming `tb` is a `CheckBox` or some other `CompoundButton`).

Comment: The loop was the problem, the object needed recreation and releasing.

Comment: @EmilAnca : Yep, it seemed that was what the problem was when I looked at the state machine diagram. Bear in mind what I said about using the `isCancelled()` method of `AsyncTask` though. It's better to have an `AsyncTask` cancelled by the `Activity` which created it rather than have the `doInBackground(...)` thread test for a condition on the UI. This is especially so if you create a stand-alone `AsyncTask` which can be re-used by different `Activities` where the UI elements might be different.